# Phpinfo() not showing curl

Tags: php, curl

I have `php_curl.dll` in `xampp/php/ext/` folder and in `php.ini` file I set `extension=php_curl.dll` (removed ';'). I also set `extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php\extensions\"` in `php.ini` file. Then I restarted the Apache, even I restarted the system 2 times. But till in `Phpinfo()` I can`t see curl. and I am getting error like`"Call to undefined function curl_init()"`

I have PHP version 5.2.4.

Comment: Sometime there are several .ini files that PHP can use, are you sure you updated the right one?

Comment: `extension_dir` is already set to `C:\xampp\php\ext` for me. Try moving your `php_curl.dll` into that directory.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I installed Xampp 1.6.4. I did not uploaded any php_curl.dll file. Can you give me a link to download php_curl.dll?

Comment: You mentioned that you set `extension_dir` to `C:\xampp\php\extensions`, yet you put the actual extension in `C:\xampp\php\ext`?

Answer (score 2):

Check your Apache's `error_log` file. Even if `php_curl.dll` is activated in your `php.ini`, a startup problem might disable your `php_curl.dll`, so it doesn't show up in `phpinfo()`. Search for any line like this:

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library`

Also check that the correct `php.ini` is loaded (is shown at the beginning of `phpinfo()`) and that your `extension_dir` is correctly configured.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't been checking my error logs >.<. After doing that I could see it wasn't loaded, so I followed the steps in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40425431/1001328

Answer (score 1):

"At http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/ . Download the file that you need from the fixed curl extensions list at the bottom of the page, for example Windows 7 64 bit Machines will work correctly with the non nts file."

Source: http://www.developingtheweb.co.uk/php-5-4-3-and-5-3-13-curl-extension-fix/

Answer (score 0):

Not every `php_curl.dll` is compatible with your system configuration. Make sure you are using a compatible version of the extension.

Yet, to make sure that you are editing the correct php.ini, you can read the phpinfo's output. It will tell you which php.ini file has been loaded. Make sure that you are modifying the same file.

Comment: I uncommented the extenssion in 2 places. in php.ini under PHP directoey and another php.ini under apache/bin directory. Then i restarted the XAMPP. it is woking fine then

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the entire path instead of the relative path.

Changing that line to this fixed it for me:
extension="C:\php\ext\php_curl.dll"