# cURL not showing up in phpinfo even though is is in php.ini

Tags: php, curl, wamp, wampserver

I keep getting the error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()` and cURL does not show up in phpinfo().

Important info:

- Windows 8 x64
- I am running WAMP
- `extension=php_curl.dll` is not commented out in php.ini
- I am positive that I am checking the correct php.ini file
- In the WAMP menu under `PHP > PHP Extensions` php_curl is checked
- I have restarted all services in WAMP

I don't know what else to try. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the dll exist in the plugin library directory?

Comment: Well it exists in `php5.4.3\ext` with all other extensions. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Thanks for saving my time !! I had got same problem and after reading your solution, i followed same thing and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it's working now. I had to go here: http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/ and download the php_curl.dll which corresponds with my version of PHP.

I found this here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18576165/2525699

> "At
>   http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/
>   . Download the file that you need from the fixed curl extensions list
>   at the bottom of the page, for example Windows 7 64 bit Machines will
>   work correctly with the non nts file."

Answer (score 0):

search your c:\wamp\ for php.ini;

comment out extension=php_curl.dll in **all** of the files found.

Comment: comment out or uncomment? All php.ini files as well as phpForApache.ini have that line uncommented.