# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library php_curl.dll impossibile find

Tags: php, curl, dll, php-curl

I have Windows 10 with WAMP server (Apache 2.4.9, PHP 5.5.29 VC11 x64, e MySQL). All works fine, but now I will use curl extension.

I go into `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.29\phpForApache.ini` (from webserver configuration) and remove the comment from `extension=php_curl.dll`

reload apache server and in `error_log` I have

> **[22-Sep-2015 13:13:30 UTC] PHP Warning:**  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.29/ext/php_curl.dll' -
>   Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.in Unknown on line **0**

The DLL is on the correct folder and the other DLLs work fine.

**1° try**: I added in system var PATH: `C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.29/ext/;c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.29/`

**2° try**: I have re-dowload the file `php-5.5.29-Win32-VC11-x64.zip` and replaced the `php_curl.dll`

But I have always the same result:
`index.php`

> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined function **curl_exec()**

`phperror_log:`

> **[22-Sep-2015 13:13:30 UTC] PHP Warning:**  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.29/ext/php_curl.dll' -
>   Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.in Unknown on line **0**

Comment: *in Unknown on line 0* this is odd. Can you see curl information on `phpinfo();` ?

Comment: only "cURL  Sterling Hughes " in modules author

Comment: if i comment an uncomment php_imap.dll i see the load e not load module , but the curl don't work never

Comment: myabe there is something in window 10

Comment: sometimes, it happens just because of incompatible `curl version`, you can test it by downloading 32/64 bit curl libs

Comment: Do you still have that problem? It solved for me when I copied `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` from another curl installation into Apache's `bin` folder.

Comment: also me i had solved when i copied these files

Comment: next time dont copy your error message on your native language. By accident, I know this is Italian, and "cant find the module"

Answer (score 21):

These steps worked for me:

1. Add the main php folder onto the Path Env variable in Windows (so
   libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll are path-accessible ... some people
   copy these to Windows/System32 to make them path-accessible but that
   isn't really elegant way to solve issue)
2. Add the Apache bin folder onto the Path Env variable in Windows
3. Copy the file libssh2.dll from the php folder to apache's bin
   folder (Apache seems to need this for php's curl to work in Windows)

Comment: Only the 3rd method worked for me on PHP 5.6.31 with Apache 2.4.28.

Comment: The 3rd method worked for me also, on the same configuration than @ilhan.

Comment: "Add the main php folder onto the Path Env variable" juste that, perfect !

Comment: Number 3 does the trick. 1 and 2 are not needed, as it's clear in the original post that Apache is already looking in the right place for the dll. The problem is it can't load it.

Comment: Only the 3rd method worked for me on apache 2.4.48 and php 8.1.0. Thx a lot !!!

Comment: Regarding "Add the Apache bin folder onto the Path Env variable in Windows":

It worked for me only by adding to System variables. It didn't work for "User variables for USERNAME", so not to be confused :)

Comment: Thank you so much. The 3rd was the solution. I had a different version of the lib on Apache' bin dir. I changed it for the correct version on php

Answer (score 15):

PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' ...
Uncommenting 2 lines in the php.ini file solves this

1. Open php.ini
2. Remove semicolon to uncomment  `;extension_dir = "ext"`
   If your php is in C under the folder "php" for example, your extension_dir = "ext" should be put as extension_dir = "C:\php\ext"
3. Remove semicolon to uncomment  `;extension=curl`
4. Save php.ini

Comment: This worked for a PHP 8.x installation

Comment: worked for me on php8.2 but don't forget to make service apache2 restart

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me:

1. I copied libssh2.dll, libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll, libssl-1_1-x64.dll, ssleay32.dll, libeay32.dll to Apache bin folder. Probably not all of those are needed.
2. In php.ini, make sure the extension curl is loaded. This will be `extension=php_curl.dll` for php < 7 and `extension=curl` in php 7
3. Restart Apache Service

Comment: For me it was sufficient to copy `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that in `php.ini`, `extension_dir =`  points to the correct path if it's uncommented.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is an incompatibility between the version of apache and php, at least if you're using wampserver and/or missing VC++ executables. I was using php 7.4.11 and apache 2.4.27. Upgrading to apache 2.4.46d and installing missing executables solved the problem. That version of apaache also requires updating wampserver to 3.2.5. Make sure ALL the windows VC++ executable are installed. There is a small tool to check this. The updates and tools are found at https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/

@see http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,151396

I performed the wampserver/apache update and installed some missing VC++ files all at once, so I can't be certain which thing actually fixed the problem loading curl.

Comment: After spending several hours looking for a solution, upgrading apache solved my curl problem !

Answer (score 0):

Add to Apache httpd.conf:

```
LoadFile "C:/Php56/libssh2.dll"
LoadFile "C:/Php56/libeay32.dll"
LoadFile "C:/Php56/ssleay32.dll"
```

Answer (score -1):

i was facing the same error with wamp on windows
the problem solved when i deleted another app using php (and making conflict) and reinstall wamp